# Set custom timeout for C# Webrequest

Tags: c#, timeout, webrequest

I've checked some of the stackoverflow questions about this but still can't figure out to get the solution.

I'm using the GetRequestStream() function of webrequest class to get the response from the webservice. In fact, I'd like to set the timeout for this function. For example, if the GetRequestStream() is not able to connect in 10 seconds, the program will automatically exit from running. Please kindly advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http:www.google.com");
            request.Timeout = 10000;
```